# C++ sync and backup framework

Tags: c++, c, backup

I'm looking for a commercial/open source backup library in C++.

I have seen the Microsoft sync Framework but unfortunatly it requires the .net framework to be installed...

Thank you
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Yep, rsync:

http://librsync.sourceforge.net/

Or if you really want a complete backup (rather than sync) codebase, use the source of rdiff-backup.

Answer (score 0):

There's rsync/rsyncd, which is available on cygwin for Windows.

Also [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) is open source, but requires linux/unix on the server.